# Is it possible to sum cells from two different tables with the same figure from another cell

Tags: sql

Apologies if my terminologies aren't 100% correct as I am new to this.

I am currently trying to use a query to produce a table, however I need to sum together figures from two different tables with the same figure from another cell.

example:

Sales table
columns: folio_id and item_amount

payments table:
columns: folio_id and payment_amount

I have two separate quires but need some way to link them together.

Sales:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FT.FOLIO_ID AS FOLIO_ID,
    SUM(FT.PRICE_WITH_SURCHARGES) AS TOTAL_CHARGES
FROM    DEV.VR_FIT_SALES FT
WHERE   FT.PRICE_WITH_SURCHARGES <> 0
AND FT.ITEM_OPERATING_DAY IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY    FT.FOLIO_ID
```

payments:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FT.FOLIO_ID AS FOLIO_ID,
    SUM(FT.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_CHARGES
FROM    DEV.VR_FIT_PAYMENTS FT
WHERE   FT.AMOUNT <> 0
GROUP BY    FT.FOLIO_ID
```

I can't just join the tables as there may be entries for folio_id in one and not in the other and then vis versa. ideally i'm looking for one row for each folio_id that sums up item_amount and payment_amount.

is anyone able to help.

thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want total charges and payments per folio, then you need to bring the results from the two queries into the same row.  One method uses `UNION ALL` and aggregation:

```
SELECT FOLIO_ID,
       SUM(TOTAL_CHARGES) as TOTAL_CHARGES,
       SUM(TOTAL_PAYMENTS) as TOTAL_PAYMENTS
FROM ((SELECT FT.FOLIO_ID AS FOLIO_ID, SUM(FT.PRICE_WITH_SURCHARGES) AS TOTAL_CHARGES, 0 AS TOTAL_PAYMENTS
       FROM DEV.VR_FIT_SALES FT
       WHERE FT.PRICE_WITH_SURCHARGES <> 0 AND
             FT.ITEM_OPERATING_DAY IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY FT.FOLIO_ID
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT FT.FOLIO_ID AS FOLIO_ID, 0, SUM(FT.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PAYMENTS
       FROM DEV.VR_FIT_PAYMENTS FT
       WHERE FT.AMOUNT <> 0
       GROUP BY FT.FOLIO_ID
      )
     ) F
GROUP BY FOLIO_ID;
```

Comment: this is amazing, thank you so much. it's worked on all but one part of my query. I had to add in a extra column but I know seem to be multiplying the sum of the payments. eg it is multipmying the sum of the payments by the number of results from sales. can you help?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT P2.FOLIO_ID AS FOLIO_ID, 0 AS TOTAL_CHARGES, SUM(P2.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PAYMENTS
       FROM DEV.VR_PMS_PAYMENTS P2,
 DEV.VR_PMS_SALES P3
       WHERE P2.FOLIO_ID = P3.FOLIO_ID
 AND P2.AMOUNT <> 0
 AND P2.PMS_OPERATING_DAY <= '03-DEC-2014'
 AND P3.CHECKIN_DATE <= '03-DEC-2014'
       GROUP BY P2.FOLIO_ID

Answer (score 0):

Just put them into sub-queries, then join em.

If `FULL JOIN` is supported by your DBMS, then here's a query that would return the FOLIO_ID that are in any of the 2 tables.
An `INNER JOIN` would return only the FOLIO_ID that are in both.

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(SALE.FOLIO_ID, PAYMENT.FOLIO_ID) AS FOLIO_ID,
SALE.TOTAL_SALE_CHARGES,
PAMENT.TOTAL_PAYMENT_CHARGES
FROM 
(
    SELECT FOLIO_ID
    , SUM(PRICE_WITH_SURCHARGES) AS TOTAL_SALE_CHARGES
    FROM DEV.VR_FIT_SALES
    WHERE PRICE_WITH_SURCHARGES <> 0
      AND ITEM_OPERATING_DAY IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY FOLIO_ID
) AS SALE
FULL JOIN
(
    SELECT FOLIO_ID
    , SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PAYMENT_CHARGES
    FROM DEV.VR_FIT_PAYMENTS
    WHERE AMOUNT <> 0
    GROUP BY FOLIO_ID
) AS PAYMENT ON SALE.FOLIO_ID = PAYMENT.FOLIO_ID
ORDER BY FOLIO_ID;
```